# How to post the modal value in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is my html that I have a modal popup window and a link and when the user click on submit i like to grab the data how would i do that?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post }))
{ 

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

}

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { id = @item.ID }, new { @data_toggle = "modal", @data_target = "#myModal" })
```

Comment: Are you wanting to post the data using ajax?

Comment: I do not have any specific but I'm looking for something very straight forward easy to use and handle

Comment: Hard to give an answer if you don't even know what you want to do :). But to post the form to a controller method using ajax, it would be `$('#yourButtonId').click(function() { $.post(yourUrl, $('form').serialize(), function(data) { // do something with the returned value }); });`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my reply anyway.. why would you prefer jquery over other standard way? any reason

Comment: Actually, looking at your form, there is nothing to post back anyway - none of your controls have `name` attributes. You should be strongly binding to a model using html helpers (@HtmlTextBoxFor()` etc.)

Comment: yes I'm aware of that and I'm in process of changing to razor code :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you need to use ajax (that's why I asked in my first comment). If you want a standard submit, then change the 'Save Changes' button to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `name` attributes to your input controls and make the button type `Submit` and remove nested forms for your html, as show below -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" name="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" name="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

Then add the following `Home` controller action for `post` -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Message)
{
    return View();
}
```